# CXF Web Service Error - javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unconnected sockets not implemented

Tags: web-services, ssl, cxf

I get the following error when attempting to connect to a web service via SSL.

javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unconnected sockets not implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble finding the answer to this question. Hopefully this will help anyone else who runs into this issue.

If someone wants to copy / paste this answer I'll accept it.

CXF + SSL doesn't work with the latest jdk1.6.0_10, I downloaded jdk 1.5
and it all worked fine, and then I tried jdk1.6.0_06 and it worked fine.
(Some where along the line I upgraded to _10 in attempts to fix some other
jvm crashes I had with eclipse and I'd forgotten I'd done that.)

[Referenced](http://www.nabble.com/how-to-enable-ssl-programmatically-on-the-client-td18599103.html)

Answer (score 1):

This has also been fixed in all the recent releases of CXF.   I'd suggest also upgrading your CXF version.